# Android unhandled exception error

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm try to figure out this for a while, so I have a method that is calling a count() method that is suppose to throw and exception

the count() method

```
public int count() throws ParseException {
  return something that may throw the ParseException
}
```

and then calling from here

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(className);
query.fromLocalDatastore();

int result = 0;

try {
   result = query.count();
} catch (ParseException e) {
   result = 0;
}

return result;
```

Now I have been trying different scenarios but no matter what the IDE still not compiling and give me the following error

```
Error:(254, 11) error: exception ParseException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Error:(253, 33) error: unreported exception ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

in the line result = query.count();

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, thanks for any help

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two **different** `ParseException` classes?

Comment: If you are using parse sdk then make sure your import is `com.parse.ParseException`.

Comment: yes, that was the issue there are 2 classes with the same name, but in other package, not sure why the IDE imported the wrong one, maybe u can put the comment as an answer to marked as correct, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot catch exception that will never thrown by your try block as error suggested

```
try {
   result = query.count(); // this statement not throwing ParseException
} catch (ParseException e) { // you are trying to catch ParseException that never gonna throw. 
   result = 0;
}
```

It is like

```
    try {
           .... code // throws ExceptionA
        }
    catch (ExceptionB e) { // and calling ExceptionB

        }
```